# Does Sure Strike damage include the value from the damage workspace?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, fighter

Sure Strike seems to be the only Fighter action with 1[W] for the hit formula. Does this mean that the damage workspace value is not applied?

My character's damage workspace value is 8. When I successfully attack with my magical battle axe (1d10 damage) and roll a 5 for damage, is the damage amount 5 or 5+8=13?

Comment: damage workspace value? Do you mean your Strength Ability Score?

Comment: @EtiennevanDelden not likely.  There's a damage workspace on the 4e character sheets.

Answer (score 3):

You would gain all the damage bonuses from your damage workspace minus your ability modifier.

*Sure Strike* works like any other power. And like any other power, other bonuses are still added to the damage. The only exception here is that you don't get to add your ability (strength) modifier because the power doesn't say you do.

The workspace is broken up into 4 types of bonuses that apply to a damage roll.

1. is your ability modifier. As I've already stated, *Sure Strike* doesn't say you add your ability modifier to the damage so it's not applicable in this case.
2. is feat bonuses. Assuming the requirements for this bonus are still met, it should still be applicable. I.E. if you're a Dwarf, attacking with an axe, and you have the Dwarven Weapon Training feat, that should still very much apply to *Sure Strike.*
3. is enhancement bonuses from magic items. If you're making an attack with a magic weapon that gives you a bonus to damage rolls than that still applies.
4. is miscellaneous. Things like racial bonuses, situational bonuses, or whatever. Assuming you have any bonuses in this space and nothing *else* is preventing you from add it, than it should still apply to *Sure Strike.*